# Ignore enclosing braces with JSON parser while serializing object in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonparser

I have the following classes:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class User {

    private String id;
    private List<Reference> references;
.....
}
```

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Reference {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String ref;

    public Reference(final String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public Reference() { }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

}
```

When serializing to XML the format is as expected, but when I try to serialize to JSON I get the following

```
"users" : [
  {
      "references" : [
      {
        "ref": "referenceID"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I need it to be:

```
"users" : [
  {
      "references" : [
        "referenceID"
    ]
  }
]
```

the braces enclosing the reference list I need it to be ignored without the attribute name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the `ref` field in your `Reference` class with the [`JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) annotation that indicates that *the value of annotated accessor  is to be used as the single value to serialize for the instance*:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Reference {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    @JsonValue //<-- the new annotation
    private String ref;

    public Reference(final String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public Reference() { }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }

}

User user = new User();
user.setReferences(List.of(new Reference("referenceID")));
//it prints {"references":["referenceID"]}
System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(user));
```

**Edit**: it seems that the `JsonValue` annotation invalidates the serialization of the class as expected by the OP; to solve this problem one way is the use of a mixin class for the `Reference` class and putting inside the `JsonValue` annotation, the original `Reference` class will be untouched:

```
@Data
public class MixInReference {
    @JsonValue
    private String ref;
}


ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//Reference class is still the original class
jsonMapper.addMixIn(Reference.class, MixInReference.class);
////it prints {"references":["referenceID"]}
System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(user));
```

Comment: It worked, but I had to add it to the get method , now I am having an issue with the XML parser because the schema definition says it should have both <references> and <reference ref="value"> so the validation is failing because the reference value is not an attribute

Comment: I'm not sure about your issue, there is a xml schema and the validation is failing because of the json annotation ?

Comment: I need to be able to serialize to both JSON and XML using the same objects, with XML I was working as expected each reference has the ref value as an attribute e.g. `<reference ref="value">`, now after adding the @JsonValue it works with the JSON serialization but not with the XML, the `ref` is not an attribute and it's serialized like `<reference>value</reference>` so it fails because it's expecting the attribute

Comment: @zepol I understood now, I updated my code to solve the xml serialization problem.